# Printing from browser overflows page size

Tags: html, css, browser, printing, id-card

I'm trying to generate student id cards using HTML and CSS. In the browser the ID card appears perfectly: [ID card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLS2U.png) The problem is that it generates two pages when I try to print from the browser. Even when I print directly in the card printer (Evolis Zenius) or when I print into a PDF file. [Two pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U5PO.png)

The CSS code I'm using is:

```
*
        {
            margin:00px;
            padding: 00px;
            
        }

        .container
        {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-around;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .font
        {
            
            height: 375px;
            width:225px;
            position: relative;
            border-radius:10px;
            background-image:url('ecardbgfinal.png');
            background-size: 225px 375px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        
        .companyname{
            color:White;
            
            padding: 10px;
            font-size:25px;
        }

        .tab {padding-right:30px;}

        .top img
        {
            height: 90px;
            width:90px;
            background-color:#e6ebe0;
            border-radius:57px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 60px;
            left: 102px;
            object-fit: content;
            border:3px solid rgba(255 , 255 , 255 , .2);
            
        }
        .ename{
            position: absolute;
            top: 160px;
            left: 90px;
            color:white;
            font-size:16px;
        }
        .edetails
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 212px;
            text-transform:capitalize;
            font-size: 11px;
            text-emphasis: spacing;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
        .signature{
            position: absolute;
            top: 75%;
            height: 80px;
            width: 160px;
        }
        .signature img{

            height: 40px;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 15px 00px 00px 5px;
            border-radius: 7px;
          
        }


        .barcode img
        {
            height: 65px;
            width: 65px;
            text-align: center;
            margin:5px;
            
        }
        .barcode
        {
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            top:62.5%;
            left: 135px;
        }
        

        .qr img
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 85%;
            left: 32%;
            height: 30px;
            width:120px;
            margin:20px;
            background-color:white;
            
        }
        .edetails .Address
        {
           
            width: 60%;
            text-align: justify;
        }
```

And the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IDCard.css">
    <title>ID Card</title>
   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="padding">
        <div class="font">
            <div class="companyname">Planics<br><span class="tab">Solution</span></div>
            <div class="top">
                <img src="character.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <div class="ename">
                <p class="p1"><b>SMIT ZADAFIYA</b></p>
                <p>Media Developer</p>
                </div>
                <div class="edetails">
                    <P><b>Mobile No :</b> 8460304196</P>
                    <p><b>DOB :</b> 02/11/2020</p>
                    <div class="Address"><b>Address : </b>223 par-1 hari soc, near main road ,L.H road surat ,L.H road </div>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="signature">
                    <img src="signature.png" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="barcode">
                    <img src="qr sample.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="qr">
                    <img src="barcode.png" alt="">
                </div>

          
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested with several browsers but it's always the same. Regards, Joaquin

Comment: Have you checked your printer tool? There might be some settings to adjust.